# "Painless Conjugate Gradient": alpha minimizes f when the directional derivative $\frac{df(x1)}{d\alpha} = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

I am reading the "Painless Conjugate Gradient Method" http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf

On page 6, after equation 9, the author states "From basic calculus, $\alpha$ minimizes f when the directional derivative $\frac{df(x1)}{d\alpha} = 0$

I find this confusing because $\alpha$ is a scalar quantity, and the directional derivative is suppose to be along a vector.

I tried finding another source (http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ferris/cs730/chap3.pdf page 41) that describes this direct line search, thinking that perhaps there was a typo, however they also take the derivative with respect to $\alpha$ to minimize the function.

I feel like I am missing something painfully obvious, but I don't see how they can take a directional derivative with respect to a scalar quantity. And \alpha must be a scalar quantity otherwise the other expressions in the text wouldn't make sense, like equation 9: $x1 = x0 + \alpha*r0$ where x0,x1,and r0 are all vectors, so $\alpha$ must be a scalar.

Comment: Notice that $x_{(1)}$ is a function of the scalar $\alpha$, and these points all lie on a straight line. Shewchuk defines the directional derivative as $\frac{d}{d\alpha}f(x_{(1)}(\alpha))$, and this makes sense: If you use the chain rule you see that this evaluates to $\nabla f \cdot r_{(0)}$, i.e., the dot product of the gradient of $f$ with the vector $r_{(0)}$. The gradient of $f$ at $x_{(1)}$ depends on $\alpha$, and you want to look for a value of $\alpha$ such that the expression vanishes.

Comment: Look at Figures 6 and 7 on page 7 to see what is going on geometrically.